# arc transition issue with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

```
// last line doesn't work 
var gaugeNiddle = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(gaugeCircleX(0))
    .endAngle(gaugeCircleX(1))
    .outerRadius(gaugeCircleY(config.radius))
    .innerRadius(gaugeCircleY(0.3*config.radius));
gaugeGroup.append("path")
    .attr("d", gaugeNiddle)
    .style("fill", "001010")
    .attr('transform','translate('+config.radius+','+config.radius+')');    

// here is stop working
gaugeNiddle.transition().duration(1000).attr('innerRadius',250);
```

Comment: What's the exact problem? Could you be more detailed? Have you seen any errors in a console?

Comment: I'm not sure what;s the exact problem.
Console shows:"Uncaught TypeError: gaugeNiddle.transition is not a function"

Answer (score -1):

Got it. Should be:

```
var gaugeNiddle = gaugeGroup.append("path")
    .attr("d", gaugeNiddle)
    .style("fill", "001010")
    .attr('transform','translate('+config.radius+','+config.radius+')');
```